# Sending javascript array to php via JSON doesn't work

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a javascript array and want to send it to the php via form input hidden field. What i'm doing is here:

html:

```
<form method="post" action="a.php" onSubmit="fun();">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenF" value="">
</form>
```

and in javascript:

```
function fun()
{
    var jArray = [ "One", "Two", "Three"];

    document.getElementsByName("hiddenF").value = JSON.stringify(jArray);
}
```

and finally in php that i need an array doing like below but i don't get anything on page.

```
$arr=json_decode($_POST['hiddenF']);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: </form? should be </form>. also I think that if you want to get an array in php you need to add $arr=json_decode($_POST['hiddenF'],true);

Comment: what is the result of `echo $_POST['hiddenF'];`?

Comment: </form> maybe in the future!!, i have also tried it but got no result with $arr=json_decode($_POST['hiddenF'],true);  !!

Comment: doesn't onSubmit need to return "true"  ?

Comment: Are you sure the function fun() is being executed?

Comment: btw, is impossible to **get nothing**, at least a response header... that you can share here

Comment: You can also try tapping window.onsubmit instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onsubmit

Comment: the result of echo $_POST['hiddenF']; is nothing but in javascript the value is saved to hiddenF like [ "One", "Two", "Three"].

Comment: yes i am sure that the fun() IS EXECUTED because i tested with alert

Comment: Just a warning, the JSON object is not implemented in many not so old browsers. You may want to look at `http://www.json.org/js.html` to see how to make it available in browsers that dont implement it natively.

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementsByName("hiddenF")` returns an array. So you need to add [0] to access your hidden input.

Should be like that:

```
document.getElementsByName("hiddenF")[0].value = JSON.stringify(jArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by using ID attribute..This will work

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $arr = json_decode($_POST['hiddenF']);
    print_r($arr);
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fun()
{
    var jArray = [ "One", "Two", "Three"];
    document.getElementById("hiddenF").value = JSON.stringify(jArray);
}

</script>

<form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>" onSubmit="fun();">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenF" value="" id="hiddenF">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

If you want to make it work with name attribute, go with above answers.

Answer (score 0):

The function `document.getElementsByName` return an array, so you can't change the `.value` of this array.

```
// ...
document.getElementsByName("hiddenF")[0].value = JSON.stringify(jArray);
```

But I suggest you to use `getElementById` instead.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hiddenF" name="hiddenF" value="">
```

JS:

```
// ...
document.getElementById("hiddenF").value = JSON.stringify(jArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Java Script:**

```
function fun(){
    var jArray = [ "One", "Two", "Three"];
    document.getElementsByName("hiddenF")[0].value = JSON.stringify(jArray);    
}
```

**Html Form:**

```
<form method="post" action="process.php" onSubmit="return fun();">
    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenF" value="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

**Process.php**

```
<?php
$arr=json_decode($_POST['hiddenF']);
print_r($arr);
?>
```